# Errors when uploading image to Earth Engine directly from the Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, image-classification, tensorflow

I wanted to upload the image to Earth Engine directly from the Cloud Storage bucket with the earthengine command but encountering some errors

```
!earthengine upload image --asset_id={OUTPUT_ASSET_ID} --pyramiding_policy=mode {OUTPUT_IMAGE_FILE} {json_file}
```

The error I am getting is

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:96: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
Running command using Cloud API.  Set --no-use_cloud_api to go back to using the API

W0713 14:28:15.961857 140060284811136 __init__.py:46] file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 42, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    "file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth"
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
I0713 14:28:15.962398 140060284811136 discovery.py:275] URL being requested: GET https://earthengine.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1alpha&prettyPrint=false
W0713 14:28:16.733417 140060284811136 __init__.py:46] file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 42, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    "file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth"
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
I0713 14:28:16.733834 140060284811136 discovery.py:275] URL being requested: GET https://earthengine.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1alpha&prettyPrint=false
I0713 14:28:17.517665 140060284811136 discovery.py:894] URL being requested: GET https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/algorithms?prettyPrint=false&alt=json
I0713 14:28:18.079694 140060284811136 discovery.py:894] URL being requested: POST https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/image:import?alt=json
Started upload task with ID: V3CZNAXF5NQVG35ID753SFYF
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

This error in uploading assets is actually not an error!! (or it is.. but doesn't bother our task, surprisingly).

If you notice at the end of the error message, it says 'Started upload task..'. This means the upload task has been initiated on the GEE server and if you then head to your GEE portal (https://code.earthengine.google.com), you will find a task running in the tasks tab, which should upload the raster to GEE.

Also, sometimes, the task fails after a few seconds (saying 'cannot read mixer').  In that case, you just need to rerun the upload command, making sure the GCS path to the mixer file is correct.